# What is the MIME type of F#?

Tags: f#, content-type, mime

What is the standard mime type of an `.fs` or `.fsx` file? Is it ok to use `text/x-fsharp` or `text/fsharp`?

EDIT: By standard MIME type I meant something that F# software foundation suggests to use (if they do), not IANA.

P.S. I know there are `text/x-python` and `application/x-python-code` for Python. [Deno](https://deno.land) uses `application/typescript` for TS. But couldn't find anything for F# files.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for an F# mime type*.  Standard MIME types are governed by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#text) (python and typescript are not standard) as used by browsers.  `text/plain` is sufficient.

In Debian systems, [you can create your own "mime" types to add icons to your file extensions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes). You could create your own text/x-fsharp if you fancy.

If you what you wanted is to be able to autorun fsx scripts in Linux just add:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env dotnet fsi
```

to the top of your  script file and make it executable

```
chmod +x file.fsx
```

Comment: It could be useful to have a mime-type that everyone agrees on. A more accurate mime-type than `text/plain` can come in handy in some situations. For example, Insomnia rest client uses mime types to correctly highlight syntax of the code in the HTTP body.

Comment: @Avestura I don't understand that scenario. Why would you have F# in the HTTP body? Further why would you download f# code using a REST client?

Comment: @Keonig Lear there are plenty of cases you might have F# in the body. For example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/fsharp/main/src/fsharp/AccessibilityLogic.fs

Comment: @Keonig Lear Imagine you have a tool like curl, but it can syntax highlight the output based on the content type. And there are plenty of cases you may want to curl an fsx file, or any other script.

Comment: @Avestura I don't see the point of doing that when you could visit https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/AccessibilityLogic.fs. or you could clone the project and view sytnax highlighting with your favorite editor.

Comment: @Avestura but since you mention the F# foundation, and you still think is worthwhile, why don't you raise an issue with the foundation https://github.com/fsharp/fsfoundation/issues